# Как пишутся названия орудий пыток?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, прописная-строчная, кавычки

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишутся названия орудий пыток (нужны ли кавычки и/или прописные буквы)? Стул ведьмы, железная дева, испанский сапог, медный бык, груша и пр.? Возможно, никак и не стоит выделять по аналогии со специальными инструментами? Ср.: козья ножка (стоматологический инструмент из "Хирургии" А. Чехова).

Comment: Снова обращаюсь ко всем участникам: отмечайте, пожалуйста, те вопросы, на которые отвечаете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотя в правилах отсутствуют рекомендации по написанию таких наименований, тем не менее в интернете подобные наименования пишутся со строчной и в кавычках. И это логично, поскольку все наименования употребляются в переносном значении и не являются,как верно отметил Третий глаз, индивидуальными названиями предметов.
Вот некоторые примеры.

Эта женщина была посажена на **«стул ведьмы»** и провела на нём 11 дней и ночей, одновременно палачи прижигали ей ноги раскалённым железом.

Многих обвиняемых в колдовстве сажали на стул для допроса. Его еще назвали **«стул ведьмы»** или **«стул инквизиции».**

Для особо опасных преступниц применялись **«груши».**

Достоверные сведения об использовании **«железной девы»** для пыток и казни отсутствуют.

Answer (score 3):

Как по мне, кавычки нужны, потому что это никакая ни дева, ни груша, ни бык, а лишь предметы, на них похожие, но имеющие другие функции. Так что кавычки обязательны. Заглавная буква не нужна, поскольку это не официальное название бренда и не индивидуальное название отдельного предмета.

Comment: Мне тоже хотелось кавычки поставить, но не зря вспомнил про козью ножку, которая тоже никакая не нога, а напоминающий её инструмент для других целей. И в рассказе Чехова она без кавычек...

Comment: @ShiKomarishe а у Толстого конь под всадником сломался, вопреки физике. Я бы полагался не на авторов, а на справочники и логику, особенно, когда речь о нюансах языка. Для Чехова-медика "козья ножка", вероятно, была заурядным и привычным предметом, об условности названия которого он мог даже не задуматься. ИМХО